# Match regex when variable is passed

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test a `location.pathname`. I'm passing a path to a function with regex. The path can be:

```
/dashboard
/dashboard/orders
```

And `location.pathname` can be:

```
/dashboard
/dashboard/orders
/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1
/dashboard/orders/anyOtherId
```

What I want to do is when passing `/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1` as `location.pathname` it matches only with the `path` `/dashboard/orders` and not with `/dashboard`.

Testing Regex in https://regexr.com/ I could make it work: `\/dashboard\/*`, then I tried to implement it in javascript:

```
const matcher = new RegExp(`${path}\/*`)
matcher.test(location.pathname)
```

However, when I pass a `path = /dashboard/orders` and `location.pathname = /dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1` it matches with `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/orders`. I need it to match only with `/dashboard/orders`. `/dashboard` must match only when `path` is `/dashboard` and `location.pathname = /dashboard`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Edit: To be more clear, I need it to return true when `path` is `/dashboard/orders` and `location.pathname` is `/dashboard/orders` or `/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`.

But it must return false when `path` is `/dashboard` and `location.pathname` is `/dashboard/orders` or `/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`

Comment: surley your pattern should be `\/dashboard\/orders\/*` then?

Comment: Why do you need regex in the first place? I dont really get what exactly is the use case. I'd split the pathname at each slash and work with the array

Comment: Or test with `string.startsWith(substring [, position]);` ref: https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_startswith.php

Comment: @anubhava this works when `location.pathname` is `/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`, but when it's just `/dashboard/orders` it matches with `path` `/dashboard`

Comment: You may do it like that: when you need to only match `/dashboard` not followed with `/orders/`, you may pass a  `/dashboard(?!/orders(?:/|$))(?:/|$)` pattern.

Comment: I edited a bit the post to be more clear. I need it to return true when `path` is `/dashboard/orders` and `location.pathname` is `/dashboard/orders` or `dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`. But it must return false when `path` is `/dashboard` and `location.pathname` is `/dashboard/orders` or `dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`

Comment: @anubhava this works great! But if I have `path = /dashboard/recipients` and `location.pathname = /dashboard/recipients`, how can I make it match too, but not match with `location.pathname = /dashboard`?

Comment: I'm considering anything. `location.pathname` is the URL the visitor is, and `path` is the active sidebar button. So if visitor is in a URL that contains the path, the sidebar button must be active (true). The problem is with `/dashboard`, because all URL contains `/dashboard/SomethingElse`. I thought the `/` could work, because the path and URL of `/dashboard` doesn't contain the last `/`, and all other URLs do.

Comment: ok then try: `path == location.pathname.replace(/^(\/dashboard\/[\w-]+)\/.*$/, '$1') )`

Comment: Worked like a charm @anubhava. Please answer the question with this solution, so I can mark as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `.replace` on `location.pathname` to remove everything after 2nd path component and the just compare with the `path` variable.

This solution should work for you:

```
path == location.pathname.replace(/^(\/dashboard\/[\w-]+)\/.*$/, '$1')
```

[RegEx Demo of `.replace`](https://regex101.com/r/veVc4T/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use two different regexes.
One regex -

```
 "\/dashboard(\/)?$"
```

This will match `"/dashboard"` and `"/dashboard/"`

Second regex -

```
 "\/dashboard\/orders(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\/)?)?$"
```

this will match

`/dashboard/orders`
`/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1`
`/dashboard/orders/anyOtherId`
`/dashboard/orders/`
`/dashboard/orders/5ea5c95684c28d4b7ff688e1/`
`/dashboard/orders/anyOtherId/`